# Font colors in Livechart labels for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am workin on application in WinForms and I am setting the cartesianChart properties as follows:

```
cartesianChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
{
    Title = "Time",
    FontSize = 14.0,
    Labels = label_list.AsChartValues()
});
```

Do you know how to change the color of the font of the labels describing the Axis? This is automatic Grey when the background is white. I need it to be black to print it clearly. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. First you need to get the area of the chart and then set the color as follows:

```
this.cartesianChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Red;
this.cartesianChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
```

In your case,

```
LabelStyle.ForeColor
```

should work.